# iOS - Searching for UITabBar more icon

Tags: ios, icons, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I am searching for the more icon of the UITabBar. I found this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/iPad/ui/assets/bar/UITabBarMore.png
but that is only the low resolution, I also need the high resolution.

Where can I get this icon?
Otherwise I have to draw it myself, not so tricky, but the original one would be better.

Best Regards Tim.